# How to record a video with 90 FPS with picamera V2 in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I want to use the picamera V2 via a raspberry pi 3 model b+ with 90 FPS and a resolution of 1280x720 in a python script. According to https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/fov.html the picamera V2 should be able to run with these settings but it doesn't in my python script. How do I solve the issue? Is there any command to increase the H.264 level to 4.2 in python?

If I use the command `raspivid -o video.h264 -md 6 -fps 90 -w 1280 -h 720` via console I'm receiving the message `Too many macroblocks/s: Increasing H264 Level to 4.2` but it does record a video with (close to) 90 FPS

If i run the following code as I'd like to use the camera I'm getting an error. Using the same script using `camera.framerate = 60` works completely fine.

```
import picamera
import subprocess

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1280, 720)
camera.sensor_mode = 6
camera.framerate = 90
camera.start_recording('video.h264')
camera.wait_recording(10)
camera.stop_recording()
camera.close()
```

Error Message:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/GEA/video.py", line 8, in <module>
    camera.start_recording('video.h264')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1046, in start_recording
    camera_port, output_port, format, resize, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 723, in _get_video_encoder
    self, camera_port, output_port, format, resize, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 601, in __init__
    parent, camera_port, input_port, format, resize, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 187, in __init__
    self._create_encoder(format, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 736, in _create_encoder
    'level' % macroblocks_per_s_limit)
picamera.exc.PiCameraValueError: output resolution and framerate exceeds macroblocks/s limit (245760) for the selected H.264 profile and level
```
````

Comment: push *random words*

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to PiCamera API documentation https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/api_camera.html#picamera

Starting from release 1.11 it supports additional level option for format h264.
Below line worked for me:

```
camera.start_recording(video_file, format='h264', level='4.2')
```